# XSLT: find paths between graph nodes only if they satisfy certain properties

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this sample graph as input:

```
<graph>
    <vertex name="A" rank="2">
        <vertex name="B" rank="1">
            <vertex name="C" rank="2"/>
            <vertex name="D" rank="4"/>
        </vertex>
        <vertex name="E" rank="5">
            <vertex name="D" rank="4"/>
        </vertex>
    </vertex>
</graph>
```

I would like to write an XSLT transformation which is able to extract all the path from `A` to `D` where the rank of the last node before `D` has a rank higher than `D`. For the sample input I have provided, I would like to have this output:

```
<vertex name="A" rank="2"/><vertex name="E" rank="5"/><vertex name="D" rank="4"/>
```

Until now, I am able to write the following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">    
    <xsl:template name="findLooseStructure" match="vertex[@name='A']//vertex[@name='D']">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::vertex">
            <xsl:copy select=".">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy select="."><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I don't know how to express the condition that the last node before `D` rank must be higher than `D` rank.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just by modifying the `match` expression:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">    
    <xsl:template name="findLooseStructure" 
                  match="vertex[@name='A']//vertex[@name='D' and @rank &lt; ../@rank]">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::vertex">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

FYI, `select` is not a valid attribute on `xsl:copy`.

Comment: XSLT 3.0 allows `xsl:copy/@select`.

Comment: @MichaelKay I wondered whether 2.0 or 3.0 have a use for `xsl:copy/@select`, but OP is evidently using 1.0.